# Autonomously stopping and starting an animation for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, class, animation, intervals

Take a look at my shudder class inside my Trees class:

```
class Trees {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.l = this.x - 2,
    this.r = this.y + 2,
    this.a = 0

  }
  trunk() {
    noStroke();
    fill(126, 60, 1);
    rect(this.x + 3, this.y, 14, 40);
    triangle(this.x + 10, this.y + 30, this.x - 4, this.y + 40, this.x + 24, this.y + 40);
  }
  leaves() {
    fill(71, 215, 45);
    ellipse(this.x + 3, this.y - 5, 25);
    ellipse(this.x + 10, this.y - 15, 25);
    ellipse(this.x + 17, this.y - 5, 25);
  }
  shudder() {
    let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
    if (d < 50) {
      this.a = 4;
      if (this.x < this.l || this.x > this.r) {
        this.a = this.a * -1;
      }
    } else {
      this.a = 0;
    }
    this.x = this.x + this.a;
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm making this tree shudder back and forth when I click on it which is working! However, I'm trying to simulate it shaking as if it's being stuck with an axe three times. i.e I'd like it to start juddering half a second, then stop, start, stop, start and then permanently stop.

I've tried my best as you can see here:

[image: automated shaking tree attempt]
But no dice.

I should mention I'm using the p5 Library but I don't think it would affect this too much apart from the mouseX and mouseY pre-defined functions.

Can anybody solve this puzzle?

Many Thanks!

Comment: try moving `if(counter === 3` block inside `setInterval()`

Comment: Please don't ever post pictures of code, post the code in text form.